# Why does excel have so many options to save a csv file?

Tags: windows, excel, csv

I go to save as my file in excel and there are so many different format types to save as for csv:

1. CSV (Comma Deliminated)
2. CSV (Macintosh)
3. CSV (MS-DOS)

Aren't they all the same? I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't all the same. Particularly DOS and Macintosh had different line ending characters, which this option might be referring to:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

but see https://superuser.com/a/385267/67909 this option in Excel seems to relate to foreign / accented characters.

"CSV" formatted data can vary in lots of ways:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard